# Confusion about Go syntax

Tags: go

I seen this in the `net` package source code on golang.org.

```
c, err := dial(network, ra.toAddr(), dialer, d.deadline())
if d.KeepAlive > 0 && err == nil {
    if tc, ok := c.(*TCPConn); ok {
        tc.SetKeepAlive(true)
        tc.SetKeepAlivePeriod(d.KeepAlive)
        testHookSetKeepAlive()
    }
}
return c, err
```

What is `c.(*TCPConn)` doing exactly in this case? I thought initially it was some kind of type casting, but it returns 2 values to `tc` and `ok`.

This is confusing to me. Can someone explain what this code is doing please?

[source code here](https://golang.org/src/net/dial.go) line 171.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Type assertions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)
>
> For an expression x of interface type and a type T, the primary
>   expression
>
> `x.(T)`
>
> asserts that x is not nil and that the value stored in x is of type T.
>   The notation x.(T) is called a type assertion.
>
> A type assertion used in an assignment or initialization of the
>   special form
>
> ```
> v, ok = x.(T)
> v, ok := x.(T)
> var v, ok = x.(T)
> ```
>
> yields an additional untyped boolean value. The value of ok is true if
>   the assertion holds. Otherwise it is false and the value of v is the
>   zero value for type T.

If `c` of type `Conn`, an interface type, contains a value of type `*TCPConn` then `ok` is true and `tc` is set to the value of type `*TCPConn` stored in `c`. `c` could also contain `nil`, `*UDPConn`, `*UnixConn`, et cetera. In which case, `tc` will be `nil` and `ok` will be false.

```
if tc, ok := c.(*TCPConn); ok {
    tc.SetKeepAlive(true)
    tc.SetKeepAlivePeriod(d.KeepAlive)
    testHookSetKeepAlive()
}
```